# Equality for matrix norm product of matrix * it's transpose, and square of the norm of the matrix

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

So, I know that $||AB|| \leq ||A||\cdot||B||$ (2-norm)

I'm doing a work on matrix algorithms and i seem to get as a result that $||A^TA|| = ||A||^2$

Does this always apply, or when and why does it happen?

Comment: Which matrix norm are you using?


Comment: 2-norm, sorry for not mentioning that

Comment: I think this would be much better asked on http://math.stackexchange.com/  as it's not really _research_ level.

Comment: ...and, if you do ask at stackexchange, it would be better to give, explicitly, what your _definition_ of the 2-norm is.

Comment: This is true for any norm, not just the Matrix norm induced by the vector 2-norm.

Answer (score 4):

If I'm not missing something, this is very obvious: $|A|^2_2$ is the maximal absolute value of the eigenvalues of $B = A^T A$. Thus $|A^TA|_2 =|B|_2$ is the square root of the maximal absolute value of the eigenvalues of $B^TB = B^2$. Since $B$ is diagonalizable, the eigenvalues of $B^2$ are just the squares of those of $B$.

Comment: sorry, shouldn't this be a comment then?

Comment: looks like an answer to me...

Comment: Yes, but I thought implicit MO etiquette suggested not answering blatantly non research questions, where comments would suffice. anyhow, not a big deal ;-)